# A fair coin is tossed $\text{10 times}$. What is the probability that ONLY the first two tosses will yield heads?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

### Question

> A fair coin is tossed $\text{10 times}$. What is the probability that ONLY the first two tosses will yield heads?

### My Solution

Here from the question we can conclude that the event i.e tossing $10$ coin are independent,hence

probablity of head=probablity of tail$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

---

Hence ,

$(\frac{1}{2})^2 \times (\frac{1}{2})^8 =(\frac{1}{2})^{10}=\frac{1}{1024}$

Am i correct ?Becuase answer given is $\frac{1}{4}$

Thanks

Comment: Your answer seems correct

Comment: Do you mean to say the probability of 2 heads followed by 8 tails or are 1 or 0 heads in the first two tosses permissible as well.?

Comment: Your answer is correct, because of the word "only" in the question. Their answer would be correct if the word "only" was omitted, i.e. if the remaining 8 coin tosses could have any outcomes instead of all tails.

Comment: ... or if the word “only” came towards the end of the sentence @JaapScherphuis.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ,Chase,Jaap still the answer is not clear .is it $\frac{1}{1024}$ or $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Your answer is 1/1024. Chase and I both wrote that your answer is correct. How is that not clear?

Comment: okk thank you .Actually 2 upvote on $\frac{1}{4}$ confused me .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The event in the question can happen in only one way. The total number of possible outcomes, the sample space, is
 $ 2^{10}= 1024 $. So, the probability is $ 1/1024 $.  If heads or tails were allowed in the remaining 8 tosses then the number of outcomes would be $ 2^8 = 256 $ and the probability would then be $ 256/1024 = 1/ 4 $.